# Error while starting Plone instance

Tags: macos, python-2.7, plone

I'm trying to run Plone on my mac. but I couldn't its showing the following message. Any idea about how to fix this?

```
learner-Mac:zinstance learner$ ./bin/instance fg
2015-02-14 17:14:37 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Sat Feb 14 17:14:37 2015
    Hostname: 0.0.0.0
    Port: 8080
2015-02-14 17:14:39 INFO DocFinderTab Applied patch version 1.0.5.
2015-02-14 17:14:39 WARNING ZODB.blob (12250) Blob dir /Users/learner/Plone/zinstance/var/blobstorage/ has insecure mode setting
2015-02-14 17:14:39 INFO plone.jsonapi.router DefaultRouter::__init__
2015-02-14 17:14:39 INFO plone.jsonapi.router DefaultRouter.add_url_rule: /version (apiversion) -> 'apiversion' options: {'methods': ['GET']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/bin/interpreter", line 296, in <module>
    exec(compile(__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec"))
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 76, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 22, in run
    starter.prepare()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 86, in prepare
    self.startZope()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 262, in startZope
    Zope2.startup()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 47, in startup
    _startup()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 118, in startup
    load_zcml()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 52, in load_zcml
    load_site()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/Zope2/App/zcml.py", line 46, in load_site
    _context = xmlconfig.file(site_zcml)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 649, in file
    include(context, name, package)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 352, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.22-py2.7.egg/OFS/metaconfigure.py", line 46, in loadProducts
    xmlconfig.include(_context, zcml, package=product)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 352, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 104, in includePluginsDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, filename)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 352, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 54, in includeDependenciesDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, 'configure.zcml')
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 548, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 380, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 352, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 359, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 558, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 706, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 51, in includeDependenciesDirective
    info = DependencyFinder(dist).includableInfo(['configure.zcml', 'meta.zcml'])
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.7.egg/z3c/autoinclude/dependency.py", line 26, in includableInfo
    module = resolve(dotted_name)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.dottedname-3.4.6-py2.7.egg/zope/dottedname/resolve.py", line 32, in resolve
    found = __import__(used)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/WeasyPrint-0.19.2-py2.7.egg/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 304, in <module>
    from .css import PARSER, preprocess_stylesheet
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/WeasyPrint-0.19.2-py2.7.egg/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import computed_values
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/WeasyPrint-0.19.2-py2.7.egg/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/WeasyPrint-0.19.2-py2.7.egg/weasyprint/text.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/cairocffi-0.6-py2.7.egg/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, *CAIRO_NAMES)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/cairocffi-0.6-py2.7.egg/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 34, in dlopen
    return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/cffi/api.py", line 118, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/cffi/api.py", line 411, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/cffi/api.py", line 400, in _load_backend_lib
    return backend.load_library(name, flags)
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Users/learner/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.4.1-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 98.4-102.10
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Users/learner/Plone/zinstance/src/bika.health/bika/health/configure.zcml", line 11.2-11.37
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Users/learner/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/bika.lims-3.1.5-py2.7.egg/bika/lims/configure.zcml", line 13.0-13.35
    OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2: dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 2): image not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/), and that project [requires Cairo to be installed](http://weasyprint.org/docs/install/).

You'll need to install that missing dependency. You can probably get it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), I see there is a [formula available](http://brewformulas.org/Cairo) at any rate.